# How to get Apache Curator to work inside an OSGi bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-curator

I am new to Zookeeper and Curator in general.
Trying to use Curator to connect to Zookeeper and do read-write.
This code works fine when executed from a standalone Java application, but when embedded inside an OSGi bundle, it fails to connect to the Zookeeper server.

```
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory;

CuratorFramework curator = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(
    someConnectionString, retryPolicy);
curator.start();
try {
    // returns false from OSGi, but true from standalone application
    curator.getZookeeperClient().blockUntilConnectedOrTimedOut();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) { ... }
```

For the OSGi bundle I am including curator-framework-2.9.0.jar, curator-client-2.9.0.jar and other dependencies in a lib folder inside the bundle.
I am not getting any runtime errors, so all the dependencies seem to be handled.

Tried searching if Curator libraries support the OSGi framework and I do see this issue raised in 2013 and marked as resolved.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: So, this call simply returns false, but no information as to why it failed? That makes it pretty much impossible to diagnose a cause. Is there any way to get more information?

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I agree there is very little information and I havent found anyway to gather more. Still stuck with this issue but trying out a few things, hopefully will find a way eventually..

Comment: @NeilBartlett you were spot on!! Getting the error info was the key after that it was a 5 min job. Posted the answer below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a simple case of missing imports. However the ClassNotFoundExceptions were not coming to the console but rather going to log4j. Adding the below to initialize log4j revealed the missing imports like `org.ietf.jgss`.

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

BasicConfigurator.configure();
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL);
```